# PHP pthreads die main thread when error in the child

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I am using php pthreads extension. I run console script and it must work permanently. That script create several child threads. The problem is when fatal error occurred in the child thread - main thread and other child still works. I need script will be died when error occurred in the child.

It's a big project, using Spot 2 ORM and other untypical PHP extension. TRY and CATCH it's not so easy to solve that problem. When script works a lot time, several hours, the error "mysql server has gone away" begins to appear

Comment: Isn't this just a case of `try` and `catch` then killing the scripts within the `catch`? I'm curious what the solution is here tbh. Maybe you can provide some code so that someone with more experience in this can provide an answer?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: If possible, could you provide code samples? doesn't need to be all of it, just how you are managing your threads (creating, starting, joining, etc...are you using Workers, Pool, etc... ) ? Any more info could be helpful.